# Random string generator gets the same result in Java

Tags: java, random, hashmap

Hello we are developing a Quiz game in Java.In our project we use Hashmap that consist of countries and their details.Each time in the loop we want to get three random countries with a random method, and we want  User to answer questions related to that random country.Everytime user answers the questions related to the country  we get another random country from hashmap.But we don't want these three random countries to be the same.How can we avoid that?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

public class Countries {
    private HashMap<String, String[]> countrieseasy;
    private HashMap<String, String[]> countriesmedium;
    private HashMap<String, String[]> countrieshard;
    private String previousEasyCountry;
    private String secondPreviousEasyCountry;
    private String previousMediumCountry;
    private String secondPreviousMediumCountry;
    private String previousHardCountry;
    private String secondPreviousHardCountry;
    private Random random;

    public Countries() {
        countrieseasy = new HashMap<>();
        countriesmedium = new HashMap<>();  // create a new HashMap object
        countrieshard = new HashMap<>();
        previousEasyCountry = null;
        secondPreviousEasyCountry = null;
        previousMediumCountry = null;
        secondPreviousMediumCountry = null;
        previousHardCountry = null;
        secondPreviousHardCountry = null;
        random = new Random();
    }

    public void addCountryeasy(String name, String capital, String language, String continent, String currency) {
        String[] details = {name, capital, language, continent, currency};
        countrieseasy.put(name, details);
    }

    public void addCountrymedium(String name, String capital, String language, String continent, String currency) {
        String[] details = {name, capital, language, continent, currency};
        countriesmedium.put(name, details);
    }

    public void addCountryhard(String name, String capital, String language, String continent, String currency) {
        String[] details = {name, capital, language, continent, currency};
        countrieshard.put(name, details);
    }


    public String[] getCountryeasyDetails(String name) {

        return countrieseasy.get(name);

    }

    public String[] getCountrymediumDetails(String name) {

        return countriesmedium.get(name);

    }

    public String[] getCountryhardDetails(String name) {

        return countrieshard.get(name);

    }

    private String getRandomCountryName(HashMap<String, String[]> countries, String previousCountry, String secondPreviousCountry) {
        Object[] countryNames = countries.keySet().toArray();
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(countryNames.length);
        String countryName = (String) countryNames[randomIndex];
        while (countryName.equals(previousCountry) || ( countryName.equals(secondPreviousCountry)) || (secondPreviousCountry != null && secondPreviousCountry.equals(previousCountry))) {
            randomIndex = random.nextInt(countryNames.length);
            countryName = (String) countryNames[randomIndex];
        }
        return countryName;
    }



    public String getRandomCountryeasyName() {
        String secondPreviousCountry = previousEasyCountry;
        previousEasyCountry = secondPreviousEasyCountry;
        secondPreviousEasyCountry = secondPreviousCountry;
        String countryName = getRandomCountryName(countrieseasy, previousEasyCountry, secondPreviousEasyCountry);
        return countryName;
    }





    public String getRandomCountrymediumName() {
        String secondPreviousCountry = previousMediumCountry;
        previousMediumCountry = secondPreviousMediumCountry;
        secondPreviousMediumCountry = secondPreviousCountry;
        String countryName = getRandomCountryName(countriesmedium, previousEasyCountry, secondPreviousEasyCountry);

        return countryName;
    }

    public String getRandomCountryhardName() {
        String secondPreviousCountry = previousMediumCountry;
        previousHardCountry = secondPreviousHardCountry;
        secondPreviousHardCountry = secondPreviousCountry;
        String countryName = getRandomCountryName(countriesmedium, previousEasyCountry, secondPreviousEasyCountry);
        return countryName;
    }

}
```

So here is our code we tried to give each country a string value previousName , and ckecked if it is equal to the next random country we get from hashmap but it didn't work.

Comment: *"it didn't work"* - isn't a helpful description. Please [*edit*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74864684/edit), tell what exactly fails and provide debugging details.

Comment: Start an empty Set<String>. Every time you select a country by key from your Map, check the Set for that key. If the key exists in the Set, try again to fetch another country. Else add that country key to the Set and move on to select the 2nd country and so on. Use the Set to accumulate used up countries and utilise it as a checker to prevent repeating countries.